# Open Cash Drawer via WebUSB JavaScript

Tags: webusb

I have a c# application that can open a cash drawer with the Windows Driver Installed.  Pretty simple as the driver makes the USB device appears as a serial port:

```
 SerialPort rsPort = new SerialPort(textBox1.Text);
 byte[] openCmd = new byte[5];
 openCmd[0] = 27;
 openCmd[1] = 112;
 openCmd[2] = 0;
 openCmd[3] = 60;
 openCmd[4] = 255;
 rsPort.Open();
 Thread.Sleep(100);
 rsPort.Write(openCmd, 0, 5);
 Thread.Sleep(100);
 rsPort.Close();
```

I'm now trying to open the same USB cash Drawer via WebUSB.  I've used ZaDig to install a generic USB drive and Chrome can see the USB device; can open the device; however, i'm struggling to send the correct commands.

Here is an image of the config:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript WebUSB</h2>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", talkToDrawer);

async function talkToDrawer() {
  try {
    let device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 1659 }] });
    console.log(device);
    await device.open(); // Begin a session.
    await device.selectConfiguration(1); // Select configuration #1 for the device.
    await device.claimInterface(0); // Request exclusive control over interface #2.
    result = await device.controlTransferOut({
        requestType: 'standard', // tried all combinations: standard / class / vendor
        recipient: 'endpoint', // tried all combinations: device / interface / endpoint / other
        request: 0x27,
        value: 0,
        index: 1
     });
     result = await device.controlTransferOut({
        requestType: 'standard', // tried all combinations: standard / class / vendor
        recipient: 'endpoint', // tried all combinations: device / interface / endpoint / other
        request: 0x112,
        value: 0,
        index: 1
     });
     result = await device.controlTransferOut({
        requestType: 'standard', // tried all combinations: standard / class / vendor
        recipient: 'endpoint', // tried all combinations: device / interface / endpoint / other
        request: 0x0,
        value: 0,
        index: 1
     });
     result = await device.controlTransferOut({
        requestType: 'standard', // tried all combinations: standard / class / vendor
        recipient: 'endpoint', // tried all combinations: device / interface / endpoint / other
        request: 0x60,
        value: 0,
        index: 1
     });
         result = await device.controlTransferOut({
        requestType: 'standard', // tried all combinations: standard / class / vendor
        recipient: 'endpoint', // tried all combinations: device / interface / endpoint / other
        request: 0x255,
        value: 0,
        index: 1
     });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about the device there are two errors I see in the code,

1. In the C# example the command is `[27, 112, 0, 60, 255]` with the values given in decimal while in the Javascript example the values are given as hexadecimal constants. The appropriate code for constructing the command buffer in Javascript is,

```js
const cmd = new Uint8Array([27, 112, 0, 60, 255]);
```

2. Rather than using `controlTransferOut()` to send the data it is most likely correct to use `transferOut()` and select endpoint number 3. The Prolific USB-to-serial converter chips implement a protocol similar to the standard USB serial class, which uses a pair of bulk IN and OUT endpoints for the serial data stream,

```js
result = await device.transferOut(3, cmd);
```

The remaining open question is whether you need to perform any control transfers before you can send this command. Control transfers are used to configure the device and for a USB-to-serial chip this usually involves things like setting baud rate or setting the DCE bit high. When reverse-engineering how to communicate with a USB device I recommend using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to view the USB traffic from a working driver.

Note, that if you are working with a serial device you should take a the [Serial API](https://github.com/WICG/serial/blob/gh-pages/EXPLAINER.md). There is an experimental implementation available in Chrome behind the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag. This API is designed for applications specifically targeting serial devices and avoids having to re-implement the driver for the USB-to-serial chip.